# Filter QuerySet from a given list of indexs

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a list of index i want to extract from another queryset.

```
>>> allLocation = loc.objects.all()
>>> allLocation
<QuerySet [<loc: loc object (1)>, <loc: loc object (2)>, <loc: loc object (3)>, <loc: loc object (4)>, <loc: loc object (5)>]>
>>> UserIndex  = [0,3,4]
>>> 
>>> allLocation[UserIndex[1]]
<loc: loc object (4)>
>>> filteredUser = ?
```

I can query a single item but I want to filter all the index item from my `allLocation` given the index number in a list ( `UserIndex` ) and store it in `filteredUser`

Comment: `.filter(id__in=my_index_list)`

Comment: TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got [0, 3, 4].

Comment: @moshiulRabbi: it is `id__in`, not `id`.

Comment: No, It is returning the index no. of allLocation. In the example when I gave allLocation[UserIndex[1]] , I wanted to query the index of second element of the list (3). So in allLocation case it should return the 4th element not 2nd

Comment: ``` 
>>> al
<QuerySet [<loc: loc object (1)>, <loc: loc object (2)>, <loc: loc object (3)>, <loc: loc object (4)>, <loc: loc object (5)>]>
>>> u
[0, 2, 3]
>>> al.filter(user__in=u)
<QuerySet [<loc: loc object (2)>, <loc: loc object (3)>]>
>>> 
>>> the ans i am looking for is: loc object (1),loc object (3),<loc: loc object (4)

```

Comment: include replace `my_index_list` with `my_index_list.values("id")`

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'